# Merging Solr index stored in HDFS not working

Tags: solr, lucene, hdfs, hdp

I'm trying to merge two Solr core indexes into new one using org/apache/lucene/misc/IndexMergeTool.

All indexes are saved on HDFS under path /apps/solr/data/collection_name/data/index.

So I've created a new collection say col_new, and I'm trying to merge there col_1: core_1 and core_2.

I'm using is the following:

"""
java -cp /usr/cloudera-hdp-solr/5.0.0.5-301/cloudera-hdp-solr/solr/server/solr-webapp/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/lucene-core-7.4.0.jar:/usr/cloudera-hdp-solr/5.0.0.5-301/cloudera-hdp-solr/solr/server/solr-webapp/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/lucene-misc-7.4.0.jar org/apache/lucene/misc/IndexMergeTool -destDir hdfs://namenode/path_to_new_core/data/index -srcDir hdfs://namenode/path_to_old_core_1/data/index hdfs://namenode/path_to_old_core_2/data/index
"""

The behaviour is strange. It creates a folder named hdfs: and other two named -srcDir and -destDir.

Have someone experience in merging indexes saved on a shared file system?

Other details:

- Solr version 7.4
- HDP v3
- Lucene 5.0.0

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be in the directory type that IndexMergeTool uses to read and write index files.
I am not sure about all versions, but the last version [uses FSDirectory](https://github.com/apache/lucene/blob/6445bc0a14ee22d107c072f4ef7b133faf780fe1/lucene/misc/src/java/org/apache/lucene/misc/IndexMergeTool.java#L108) to access the files.

`FSDirectory` has a few implementations, but all of them work with local file systems, not with HDFS. To access HDFS, it should use `HdfsDirectory`.

It looks like `IndexMergeTool` can't help you with merge files stored on HDFS, but you can implement your own merger using `HDFSDirectory`:

```
val part1 = HdfsDirectory(Path("path-to-part1"), hdfsConfig)
val part2 = HdfsDirectory(Path("path-to-part2"), hdfsConfig)
val output = HdfsDirectory(Path("output-path"), hdfsConfig)

IndexWriter(output, IndexWriterConfig()).use {
    it.addIndexes(part1)
    it.addIndexes(part2)
}
```

It is also important to note that writing directly to HDFS may produce performance problems if you have a lot of files in your indexes. Sometimes it may be fast to merge indexes locally and then copy to HDFS the result index.